# Coinbase API - Get all of user's wallets

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm creating an app to allow people to view their coinbase balances. Right now it seems like they'd have to authorize separately for me to view balances on each wallet. Is there any way I can allow the user to grant me access to read the balance on all of their coinbase wallets?

Comment: What does the Coinbase API documentation say?

Comment: It doesn't say much about how to allow the user to give permissions for multiple wallets, just that "Lists current user’s accounts to which the authentication method has access to".

Comment: Also to clarify the reason I'm posting this coinbase-specific question on SO is they literally don't have a support email, they say to ask any help questions here.

Comment: You may have to puzzle through this yourself by trying different things, or by engaging someone in a chat room to help you. Another option is a coaching  services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com) where you could find a Coinbase expert and pick their brain for a half hour.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue. Using OAuth2 (scope `wallet:accounts:read`) will give you access to to call `GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts` which returns a `json` list of all their wallets with balance and currency details.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/a802dd23765de72dc66f6147dd32ff6e.png

I can only ever get the check mark next to one wallet, and on my app side the JSON that is returned only ever has one account and which account it returns depends on which wallet I select on that screen. I am using the accounts endpoint you referenced. I assumed that was because it didn't have permissions for the other wallets.

Comment: And the following are the scopes I've requested: wallet:user:read,wallet:payment-methods:read,wallet:buys:create,wallet:accounts:read,wallet:user:email

Comment: @zachvac struggling with this issue as well. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @zachvac Having the same issue, please update if you figured it out! :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a scope issue. I am using the following scope (got it from example app) 'balance transactions user'. If I use my own client id/secret I get the login page with individual accounts under Wallet Access. However, if I swap out my client id/secret to the one provided in the example app 'org.cocoapods.demo.coinbase.coinbase-oauth://coinbase-oauth' I get 'The permissions above will apply to all of your wallets' message under Wallet Access section. So, it seems to me that this is a configuration issue on Coinbase side

Comment: Ok. I have finally figured it out. This is happening due to 'account' param not being provided in the URL for OAuth authentication page. (more on this here https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions)

I had to enhance coinbase-idk to include this param. Anyone knows how to contribute to coinbase-sdk project?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857809/how-to-request-access-to-all-of-the-user-accounts-using-walletaccountsread/48031203#48031203

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request access to all of the user accounts using wallet:accounts:read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857809/how-to-request-access-to-all-of-the-user-accounts-using-walletaccountsread)