# How to request access to all of the user accounts using wallet:accounts:read?

Tags: coinbase-api

When my app requests `wallet:accounts:read permission` using v2 of Coinbase API, the user is presented with a drop-down list of all accounts where he can choose only one of the three possible wallets. If my app wants to work with all three wallets (e.g. BTC, ETC, LTC), what is an elegant solution? Connecting with OAuth three times, each time requesting the user to grant access to a specific wallet is not a clean workaround. How can the app request permission to all of the accounts with a single request?

Comment: I have this same question! I emailed CoinBase yesterday, will update if they get back to me before you get an answer.

Comment: Please do, it's ridiculous

Comment: I strongly feel they messed up. There's no way I can pull info from multiple accounts as shown here: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#list-accounts

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. Super frustrating...Still haven't heard back from them.

Comment: I'm finally in touch with them, we're working to figure out what the issue is...I'll keep this updated if we get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. Thanks a lot for the update :-) Please keep posting here.

Comment: Still working on it—probably gonna be waiting another week for their response — but seems to be related to the scope permissions grant. If you create a Developer Access Token from the API portal, giving it permissions "wallet:accounts:read", using that on the `accounts` API returns all of my accounts, like we'd expect it to with the access token granted during oauth.

Comment: I noticed it earlier. Access token, indeed, has access to all of the accounts. However, OAuth2 is preferred over access tokens for an user-facing application as per the guideline.

Comment: Yep, that was just a clue that the issue was with the oauth flow. I figured it out! Posting answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Coinbase docs](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/reference), in the `GET https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize`
 portion of the Oauth flow, you can optionally specify the parameter `accounts` to configure which accounts your application has access to.

> Change the account access the application will receive. Available values:
>
> `select` *(default)* Allow user to pick the wallet associated with the application
>
> `new` Application will create a new wallet (named after the application)
>
> `all` Application will get access to all of user’s wallets
>
> For backward compatibility all is used as default for applications created prior to this change

Adding this parameter allowed me to get access to all accounts associated with a user!

Comment: Awesome finding!

Comment: I've forked the Coinbase iOS SDK repo and added the `account=all` parameter which successfully requests the user to grant access to all accounts. I'm still having issues actually accessing the account details however. Using `getAccountsList` on the Coinbase object returns only the BTC, GBP and EUR accounts (no LTC, ETH or BCH). Any suggestions as to why this might be? Scope is defined as `@"user balance, transactions"`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Coinbase example app produces the same results (only BTC and fiat wallets).

Comment: Coinbase official SDK points to v1.0 endpoints. I had to fork the repo and repoint the functionality that I needed such as balance and transaction queries to v2. I have also added the 'accounts' param as described above as well

Comment: I'm using the original Coinbase SDK. No fork. in stead, next to the `wallet:accounts:read` scope, I also add  `["accounts": "all"] `
as meta argument to the  `startAuthentication `
method and I use the .doGet method with the api v2 accounts endpoint as argument (so  `coinbase.doGet("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts", parameters: nil) {(response, error) -> Void in ` 
 to get details for all accounts.